# DBI connect('database=orthomcl;host=db;mysql_local_infile=1','orthomcl',...) failed: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, perl, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have `cat orthomcl/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:stretch-backports

RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
        cpanminus \
        build-essential \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        python \
        ca-certificates \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cpanm DBI DBD::mysql
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
orthomcl:
    tty: true
    build: orthomcl
    restart: always
    links:
        - db
    volumes:
        - ./output_dir/:/output_dir

db:
  image: mariadb
  restart: always
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="PAssw0rd"
    - MYSQL_DATABASE="orthomcl"
    - MYSQL_USER="orthomcl"
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD="PAssw0rd"
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - ./mysql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

This is the SQL config file:

```
$ cat mysql/orthomcl.sql 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `orthomcl`;
create user `orthomcl`@`db` identified by 'PAssw0rd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on `orthomcl`.* to `orthomcl`@`db`;
```

The Perl script which connections to the database is `output_dir/test.pl`

```
#!/bin/env perl  
use DBI;
require DBD::mysql;

my $dbConnectString="DBI:mysql:database=orthomcl;host=db;mysql_local_infile=1";
my $dbLogin="orthomcl";
my $dbPassword="PAssw0rd";

DBI->connect($dbConnectString, $dbLogin, $dbPassword, { RaiseError => 1 } ) or
die ( "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr );
```

Next, I used `docker-compose up` and after it I did:

```
$ docker-compose run orthomcl perl /output_dir/test.pl
Starting orthomcl_db_1 ... done
DBI connect('database=orthomcl;host=db;mysql_local_infile=1','orthomcl',...) failed: Access denied for user 'orthomcl'@'172.17.0.4' (using password: YES) at /output_dir/test.pl line 10.
```

MySQL logs shows:

```
...
db_1        | 2019-05-04  4:56:31 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1        | Version: '10.3.14-MariaDB-1:10.3.14+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
db_1        | 2019-05-04  4:58:19 8 [Warning] Access denied for user 'orthomcl'@'172.17.0.4' (using password: YES)
```

How is it possible to solve the above error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible for you to access the mariadb container with user `orthomcl` using some software like `DBeaver` or anything? Moreover how do you execute the SQL script? You put it in mariadb container and let it execute on startup?

Comment: My understanding is that the SQL script get executed automatically as long it the extenstion *.sql.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the error is that your database has not been able to resolve the IP address of the client, "172.17.0.4", back to the host name you used for the account, "db". You need to provide robust forward and backward domain name resolution in your docker environment if you want to work like this.

Alternatively, if you are happy that your docker environment (and the private IP range it uses) are sufficiently shielded from outside access, you can drop the whole idea of limiting accounts to specific client addresses, and use the "%" wildcard for the host part. If that's your approach, you may also want to add "--skip-name-resolve" to your database server configuration so that connections are not triggering useless DNS queries and possible delays.

Comment: How do I provide robust forward and backward domain name resolution in my docker environment?

Comment: Not a simple question, but I will give the simplest answer I can. The "thorough" approach is to provide your own nameserver which can perform all the forward and reverse name resolution for your environment, and ensure that all containers use that nameserver as a resolver. The "quick and dirty" approach is to document all hosts and ip addresses in a hosts file, and ensure that copies of that hosts file are placed in /etc/hosts in every container.

Comment: I should add that I'm not a docker expert (yet), and there may be special facilities offered by or for docker to deal with this kind of thing, since it's a very common need.

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure about the docker file setup but the error is:

> Access denied for user 'orthomcl'@'172.17.0.4' (using password: YES)

so grant privs to IP, range(172.%) or all

```
create user `orthomcl`@`%` identified by 'PAssw0rd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on `orthomcl`.* to `orthomcl`@`%`;
```